# In clustering, how does one estimate the distribution over the number of clusters?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, unsupervised-learning

In Murhpy's Machine Learning book pg 10, he says, when introducing clustering

> (Given unlabelled data)
> Let K denote the number of clusters. Our first goal is to estimate the distribution over the number of clusters, p(K|D); this tells us if there are subpopulations within the data. For simplicity, we often approximate the distribution p(K|D) by its mode, $K∗ = arg max_K p(K|D)$

I have two questions:
1)Given unlabelled data, how is it even possible to estimate the distribution over the number of clusters? I'd imagine there might be some technique that takes into account distances between points etc but it seems like quite a difficult? What's actually done in practice?

2)What does it mean to approximate a distribution by its mode?(Don't you need to know the distribution first to know the mode?)